# How to show all shared memory allocated by docker

Tags: docker, shared-memory

When I run a docker image with `ipc=host` and call `shmget` to allocate a shared memory in container, I can run `ipcs -m` to display this shared memory information on the host.

If I use the default ipc mode to run the docker image, I can run `ipcs -m` to display shared memory in docker, but I can not use the same method to display it on the host.

Is there any way to display all shared memory information allocated by docker container on the host，even if the ipc mode is not host？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this to get information about each container from host:

```
sudo docker inspect <container-id> | grep Mem
```

example:

```
sudo docker inspect a1776a975e3a | grep Mem
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run your container with

```
docker exec -it containerName bash
```

This will open the terminal in the docker container, in terminal use

```
df -h | grep shm
```

Sample output
[image]